# Estoy intentando pasar una tabla a MySQL worbench 8.0

Tags: mysql-workbench

```
CREATE DATABASE menagerie;
USE menagerie;
SELECT DATABASE();
show databases;

SHOW TABLES;
CREATE TABLE pet (name VARCHAR(20), owner VARCHAR(20), species VARCHAR(20), sex CHAR(1), birth DATE, death DATE);
SHOW TABLES;
DESCRIBE pet;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'mysql-pet.txt' INTO TABLE pet;
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
SET GLOBAL local_infile=1;
```

pero con SET GLOBAL local_infile=1;
me sale este error:

```
Error Code: 2068. LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.
```

y con SET GLOBAL local_infile=0;

me sale este otro error:

```
Error Code: 3948. Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides
```

me podrían decir como arreglar esto en MySQL Worbrench?
por que mire como lo arreglan con shell pero no funciona para worbrench

No entiendo, cuando esta desactivado me dice que no puede por las restricciones y cundo lo desactivo me dice que tengo que activarlas

Y una ultima pregunta: soy nuevo en el mundo de MySQL y no tengo otro servidor si no que hago todo desde local host ¿Qué me recomiendan usar MySQL worbrench o la shell?

Comment: Comentario que puede ayudar a entender la situación: MySQL es el motor de base de datos, MySQL Workbench es un programa cliente para conectarse a las bases de datos contenidas en ese MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer esto:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
SET GLOBAL local_infile = 'ON';
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
```

o esto:

```
[mysqld]
local_infile=ON
```

y reiniciar el servidor de mysql. Y recuerda es 'ON', no '1'.

Comment: Adicionalmente si quieres manejar correctamente el idioma español con acentos y eñes manejados correctamente, te falta poner la colación correcta en tu base de datos. `CREATE SCHEMA 'new_schema' DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci ;` También toma en cuenta que si tu archivo trae caracteres que no son UTF-8 tu archivo no hará el proceso completo aunque te avise que si lo hizo.